# Bitwise comparison

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

I have an array that represents an 8x8 "bit" block

```
unsigned char plane[8]
```

What I want to do is loop through this "bit" block horizontally
and count up the number of times a change occurs between 
a `1` and `0`.

When I extract a bit, it is getting stored in an
unsigned char, so basically I want to increase a count
when one char is nonzero and the other is zero.

What I have is the following:

```
int getComplexity(unsigned char *plane) {
    int x, y, count = 0;
    unsigned char bit;

    for(x = 0; x < 8; x++) {
        for(y = 0; y < 8; y++) {
            if(y == 0) {
                bit = plane[x] & 1 << y;
                continue;
            }

        /*
        MISSING CODE
        */
        }
    }
}
```

For the missing code, I could do:

```
if( (bit && !(plane[x] & 1 << y)) || (!bit && (plane[x] & 1 << y)) ) {
    bit = plane[x] & 1 << y;
    count++;
}
```

However, what I really want see is if there is some
clever bitwise operation to do this step instead
of having two separate tests.

Comment: BitScanForward intrinsic can do this for you

Comment: You could do something like `popcount(A ^ (A << 1))`. You might need to be careful around the edges though

Comment: Another option: rotate the byte one bit per `y`, as in http://ideone.com/jfcSNk

Comment: `((x && !y) || (!x && y)) == (!x != !y)`.

Comment: A more efficient method would be to precompute a table. Of course an intrinsic function is more efficient still.

Comment: Maybe `if( !( !!bit ^ !(plane[x] & 1u<<y)) )` or `if(!!bit == !(plane[x] & 1u<<y))`...

Answer (score 2):

This is really just a gcc solution because the popcnt intrinsic wont work on *every* other compiler.

```
unsigned char plane[8];

static const uint64_t tmask = 0x8080808080808080UL;

uint64_t uplane = *(uint64_t *)plane; // pull the whole array into a single uint

return __builtin_popcnt( ~tmask & (uplane ^ (uplane >> 1) ) );
```

For x86 the popcnt instruction wasnt actually implemented until sse4.2 was (so rather recently).
Also, although this looks like it relies on endianness, it doesn't because none of the individual bytes are allowed to interact thanks to the mask.
It is making some assumptions about the way memory works :\

As a side note doing this same thing in the "horizontal" direction is just as easy:

```
return __builtin_popcnt(0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFUL & ( uplane ^ (uplane >> 8) ) );
```